# Net TCP Binding Security

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

If i have written this code on Client Side then does my communication is not secured or default security will continue ? Secondly does data being transfered in Encrypted one? On Server side we have done nothing for security.

```
NetTcpBinding objNetTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
objNetTcpBinding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
objNetTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None;
objNetTcpBinding.Security.Transport.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
objNetTcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the NetTcp binding is secured at the transport level. If you disabled security on the client it must also be disabled at the server, or an exception will occur. In this scenario, the transport will not be secured.

Comment: Ok in this case how data is traversed on network? Will be it be in form of bytes and easily hackable or still it will be in encrypted form which is not hackable by common user?

Comment: The message will be binary encoded by default, but not encrypted. I believe you will need to implement an encryption system for the message before sending it.